# How to Save an uploaded Image Url in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm uploading an image as a part of the user model, and I should save the image url to display the image  in the REST Client (link like "localhost/Images/ImageName.png"),
so I saved the Image in the wwwroot this in the Post Api:

```cs
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<String> Post([FromForm]Machine mach)
        {
            try
            {
                if (mach.Files.Length > 0)
                {
                    {
                        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(mach.Files.FileName);
                        var newfilename = "Image_" + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Hours + fi.Extension;
                        var path = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath+ "\\Images\\" + newfilename);
                       /* var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\Images");*/
                     
                        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            mach.Files.CopyTo(stream);
                        }

                        Machine machine = new Machine();

                        mach.ImagePath = path;
                        
                        _context.machines.Add(mach);
                        _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                    }
                    return ("saved");

                }
```

I saved the model correctly but I got the url like this:

> "imagePath": "C:\Users\amyra\source\repos\MyApi\wwwroot\Images\Image_18.png"

I tried to display the image by "localhost:port/Images/.." but I got page not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your application's startup and make sure the `app.UseStaticFiles();` line is there. Typically it should come after `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` and before `app.UseAuthorization`

The default API template doesn't have this line.

**Edit:**
To save the URL of the image instead of the physical file path

```cs
mach.ImagePath  = new UriBuilder
{
    Scheme = Request.Scheme,
    Host = Request.Host.Host,
    Port = Request.Host.Port ?? -1,
    Path = "/Images/" + newfilename
}.ToString();
```

Though I wouldn't recommend saving the host/port/scheme part of the URL in the database as these may be subject to change.

Rather I recommend saving only the Path part

`mach.ImagePath = "/Images/" + newfilename;`

You can add the host/port/scheme part when serving the data to clients.

Comment: Thank you this is worked but I want to save this url ("localhost/images/...") while saving the other

Comment: I edited my answer. Please look at the edited answer.